# C++ Generic Vector

Tags: c++, generics, vector

Is it possible in c++ to create a vector of multiple types? I'd like to be able to build and iterate over a vector that contains many different types. For example:

```
vector<generic> myVec;
myVec.push_back(myInt);
myVec.push_back(myString);
etc...
```

The vector needs to be able to hold differing data types. Is there another vector-like type I should be using in the c++ library?

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: A vector of `boost::variant` probably.

Comment: Another choice is `boost::any`

Comment: not a `std::vector` but a `std::tuple` (in C++11). std::vector is a container of uniform types.

Comment: @AdityaKumar: But that fixes the size and the type of each element, which is much more restrictive than a vector of polymorphic objects.

Comment: Before using `boost::any`, I'd take a hard look at your code, and see if there's another, better way.  Because there is.

Comment: @MooingDuck Then... show us?

Comment: @ChristopherBales: In every single case I've seen someone ask about using `boost::any`, upon examining the code, it was _always_ better to either split the objects into separate containers, or use an array of `unique_ptr` to a virtual interface.  There are cases for `boost::any`, but they're _incredibly_ rare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html). For instance:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct my_class { my_class(int i) : x{i} { } int x; };

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::any> v;

    v.push_back(42);
    v.push_back(std::string{"Hello!"});
    v.push_back(my_class{1729});

    my_class obj = boost::any_cast<my_class>(v[2]);
    std::cout << obj.x;
}
```

If you want to restrict the set of allowed types to some defined range, you could use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct my_class { my_class(int i) : x{i} { } int x; };

int main()
{
    typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, my_class> my_variant;
    std::vector<my_variant> v;

    v.push_back(42);
    v.push_back("Hello!");
    v.push_back(my_class{1729});

    my_class obj = boost::get<my_class>(v[2]);
    std::cout << obj.x;
}
```

`boost::variant` also supports visiting. You could define a visitor that can handle all the possible types in the variant:

```
struct my_visitor : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    void operator () (int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Look, I got an int! " << i << std::endl;
    }

    void operator () (std::string const& s)
    {
        std::cout << "Look, I got an string! " << s << std::endl;
    }

    void operator () (my_class const& obj)
    {
        std::cout << "Look, I got a UDT! And inside it a " << obj.x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And then invoke it as done below:

```
int main()
{
    typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, my_class> my_variant;
    std::vector<my_variant> v;

    v.push_back(42);
    v.push_back("Hello!");
    v.push_back(my_class{1729});

    my_visitor mv;
    for (auto const& e : v)
    {
        e.apply_visitor(mv);
    }
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=97820aa85a18f7f10e96e485e95a9084-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc). The nice thing about `boost::variant` is that it will perform a compile-time check to make sure that your visitor can handle all the types that the variant can hold.

Comment: Unfortunately for `boost::any` there doesn't seem to be a good way to get the value unless you any_cast it.

Comment: You would need to do this for each type
`for (vector<boost::any>::iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); it++) {
 if (strcmp(it->type().name(),"i")==0) {
  cout << boost::any_cast<int>(*it) << endl;
 } else if (strcmp(it->type().name(),"Ss")==0) {
  cout << boost::any_cast<string>(*it) << endl;
 }
}`

Comment: @ChristopherBales: What would you possibly do with an object of an unknown type besides `any_cast` it?  For the code in this comment, the correct thing to do would be using `boost::variant` and applying the visitor pattern as described in this answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm used to C# where you can make an IEnumerable<T> add Integers (the object), Strings, whatever you want object to it. Then you can iterate over the collection with absolute ease. This apparently is a much more complicated problem in C++ because of casting issues. -- the my_visitor class for example has to make absolutely sure it covers all possible types, and therefor is not very generic

Comment: @ChristopherBales: If the visitor class doesn't cover all possible types, it throws an exception because the code can't continue.  Why would you possibly _want_ that?  You should know the types in your containers, or at least an interface for them, or else you have a container of things you can't do anything with.  Tip: it sounds like you want to have an interface.