# Creating generic vector that can be used for different structs

Tags: c++, vector

```
typedef struct {
 int a;
} a;

typedef struct {
 char b;
} b;
```

I want the vector to be able to work with both structs, the choice of which struct to use will be chosen on run-time.

Code example for clarification,

```
std::vector<????> vec;

if(argv[1]=='a'){
  vec.push_back(a());
  ..

} else if(argv[1]=='b'){
  vec.push_back(b());
  ...
}
```

Comment: And how would you ever use the vector contents?

Comment: Here are some other related questions: [\[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150475/container-of-unrelated-t-in-c)  [\[2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720211/c-generic-vector)

Comment: There are many ways to use the vector in question, but without how it is being used, the 'just use a variant' is about as good an answer as can be given.